# stopping time of brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that $W_t$ is a one dimensional brownian motion and let $a,b>0$.  The task is to find a set $A$ of full measure and a function $T$ on $A$ such that $\inf_{s \geq T(r)}(as+bW_s(r)) \geq 0$ for $r \in A$.

I think a good place to start is to use that $W_t /t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ a.s. (Strong Law of Large Numbers).

With this in mind we look at $as+bW_s(r)$=$s(a+bW_s /s)$ and if we choose $T(r)$ to be sufficiently large then our result will almost follow since the term will converge be dominated by $as$.  If we then choose $A$ to be the set where $W_s / s \to 0$ almost surely then it seems like we are very close to what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T = \min\{t : \sup_{s \geq t} W_s / s \geq -a/b \}$, which is finite almost surely by the law of large numbers and the assumption that $a,b  > 0$. Letting $A = \{T < \infty\}$, then for $s \geq T$,
$$
a s + b W_s = s(a + b W_s /s) \geq s(a + b(-a/b)) \geq 0\,.
$$
Note that $T$ is not a stopping time.